# VBA - Doesn't import XML with the customs XML scheme

Tags: excel, xml, vba, import

I've got some .XML files, that are imported in Excel incorrectly - they consist numbers more then 15 digits and they are rounded during import. To fix it - I export xml scheme to .xsd file with the code:

```
Sub save_XML_scheme()
Dim fPath As String
Dim s As String
fPath = "C:\TEMP\sc1.xsd"
s = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(1).Schemas(1).XML
Open fPath For Output As #1
    Print #1, s
    Close #1
MsgBox "Scheme is saved to C:\TEMP\sc1.xsd "
End Sub
```

and then I change in sc1.xsd property of field to string, change the scheme name to "DESSCCUPD" - (though embedded scheme name is "DESSC_Map" I need to be sure that it is different) and try to use this scheme to import .xml with the code

```
Sub xmlImportScheme()
Dim src()
Dim schm As String
src = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Choose file .xml", , True)
schm = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Choose scheme", , False)
Dim a As XmlMap
For Each x In src
Workbooks.Add

ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add schm, "DESSCCUPD"
For Each y In ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps
 If y.Name = "DESSCCUPD_Map" Then Set a = y

 Next y
 ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport Url:=x, ImportMap:=a, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("$A$1")


Next x
End Sub
```

But any way it uses embedded map name. It's interesting that variable "a" after the execution if the line  `ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport Url:=x, ImportMap:=a, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("$A$1")`  changes value to embedded map
Please help - how to fix it?

Comment: Add some sample data, such that the behavior can be reproduced at the Answerer’s end.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't show you the xml file - it's forbidden by company rules.

Comment: So, replace original content with dummy data.

Comment: how can I add here a file?

Comment: You can upload it somewhere else and add a link to your post. Alternatively, if it's not too long, just add the xml to your post as text/codeblock.